# Plotly, Python. Can i plot vertical line based on a datetime object?

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly-python

I am forecasting Covid cases and using Plotly for visualization. I would like to plot a straight vertical line in place where forecast starts. I have a chart like this.
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e02vU.png). I just want to plot a vertical line on date 25 Jan 2021, so it is visible where forecast starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you didn't share your data i tried to solve the answer with a sample code snippet from plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="GOOG")

fig.add_vline(x='2019-01-25')
fig.show()
```

I have added the following line to my code before fig.show():

```
fig.add_vline(x='2021-01-25')
```

If my date format differs from yours, you get it by printing your graph input:

```
print(df)  
           date  ...
0    2018-01-01  ...
1    2018-01-08  ...
2    2018-01-15  ...
3    2018-01-22  ...
4    2018-01-29  ...
...      ...
```

If you need more info and examples check: https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/

[My result chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcfeI.png)

Comment: Hey is there a way tp add vertical lines to the legends so I can turn it on and off?

Comment: Interestingly enough this does not work with annotations. If you add the line `fig.add_vline(x='2019-01-25', annotation="test")` the code will fail with a TypeError.

Comment: Yes, there is a bug which causes this to NOT work with annotations: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3065